# How to get div to stick to bottom of the screen when the user scrolls to it?

Tags: css

I am creating a landing page and need a div to stay at the bottom of the screen when it is scrolled to. I am using css sticky and it work when I want to stick the div to the top of the window but not the bottom. Please test on mobile dimensions.

```
<html>
<div id="page_content">
  <div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="column_12 free-tote-top-div">
      <div class="free-tote-image" style="display:none;">
      </div>
        <div class="ft-top-div-words">
        <h2 class="margin_bottom_50">Free Organic Tote</h2>
        <h1 class="margin_bottom_50 without-padding">Healthy can be<br>easy as 1, 2, 3.</h1>
        <div class="deodorant-thumbnail-mobile">
        </div>
        <p class="tote-directions">1. Make a free trial account.</p>
        <p class="tote-directions">2. Purchase any product.</p>
        <p class="tote-directions">3. Get a free tote with your first purchase.</p>
        <a href="#" class="ft-signup-btn subscribe-to-membership-45-58 subscribe-to-membership membuttonclick" style="display:none">Get Your Gift — Start Free Trial</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="free-tote-second-div">
      <h3>Get Your Gift — Start Free Trial</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="column_12 free-tote-third-div"></div>
    <div class="column_12 free-tote-review-section">
      <div class="free-tote-reviews">
        <h1>Why we love the tote.</h1>
        <div class="free-tote-review">
          <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0838/7991/files/starz3.png?14175916445677503279" alt="reviews"/>
          <p class="ft-review-words">“It’s perfect for shopping, going to the gym, or even an overnight trip.”</p>
          <p class="ft-review-name">- Nosipho M.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="free-tote-review">
          <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0838/7991/files/starz3.png?14175916445677503279" alt="reviews"/>
          <p class="ft-review-words">“Wonderful bag... Everything about it is top-notch.“</p>
          <p class="ft-review-name">- Spencer W.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="free-tote-product-carousel">
      <p>Healthy. Affordable. Eco-Friendly.<br>It’s all good.</p>
      <div class="powr-image-slider" id="ab348c59_1547667152"></div>
      <div class="ft-member-favorites row" id="mission_top_text" style="display:none">{% section 'member-favorites' %}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="free-tote-publications">
      <div class="ft-pub-top">
        <div class="ft-publication">
          <p>“Public Goods takes the guesswork out of simple, easy-to- use grooming and bathroom products.”</p>
          <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0838/7991/files/daily-beast.png?16842974685795887946" />
        </div>
        <div class="ft-publication" style="float:right">
          <p>“Household items aren’t marked up. (You pay only the amount it costs to produce the items.)”</p>
          <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0838/7991/files/buzzfeed.png?16842974685795887946" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ft-pub-bottom">
        <div class="ft-publication">
          <p>“Better quality everyday products in biodegradable or recycled packaging.”</p>
          <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0838/7991/files/forbes_09623cdb-cbcc-4ab2-9c02-4f6c53c66e78.png?16842974685795887946" />
        </div>
        <div class="ft-publication" style="float:right">
          <p>“Products are all natural from the ingredients to the physical bottles. A must have...”</p>
          <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0838/7991/files/teenvogue.png?16842974685795887946" />
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
</html>

<style>
  .row {
    width: 1500px;
  }
  .tote-directions {
    font-family: "NB";
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 26px;
  }
  .deodorant-thumbnail-mobile {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }

####################### CODE IN QUESTION ########################
  .free-tote-second-div {
    background-color: rgb(220, 136, 108);
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    bottom: 50px;
  }
  .free-tote-second-div h3 {
    padding-top: 18px;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  .free-tote-third-div {
    height: 350px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position-x: 35%;
  }
  .free-tote-review-section {
    height: 500px;
    background-color: rgb(220, 136, 108);
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
  }
  .free-tote-review-section h1 {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    font-size: 32px;
  }
  .free-tote-review {
    padding-bottom: 50px;
  }
  .free-tote-review img {
    width: 120px;
  }
  .ft-review-words {
    font-family: 'NBH';
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 95%;
    line-height: 30px;
  }
  .ft-review-name {
    padding-top: 20px;
  }
  .free-tote-product-carousel {
    height: 425px; 
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'NB' !important;
  }
  .free-tote-product-carousel p {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    line-height: 26px;
  }
  .free-tote-product-name {
    color: blue !important;
  }
  .free-tote-publications {
    height: 600px;
    background-color: rgb(220, 136, 108);
    color: #000;
  }
  .ft-publication {
    width: 48%;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .ft-publication p {
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 26px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  .ft-publication img {
    width: 50%;
    max-width: 150px;
  }
  .ft-pub-top {
    padding-top: 50px;
    width: 95%;
    padding-left: 25px;
  }
  .ft-pub-bottom {
    padding-top: 50px;
    width: 95%;
    padding-left: 25px;
  }

  @media (min-width: 1350px) {
    .free-tote-publications {
      margin-top: 125px !important;
    }
  }

  @media (min-width: 1100px) {
    .free-tote-publications {
      height: 275px !important ;
      margin-top: 75px;
    }
    .ft-top-div-words {
      padding-left: 100px;
    }
   .free-tote-image {
     margin-right: 100px;
   }
   .ft-pub-top {
     width: 45%;
     float: left;
     margin-left: 40px;
     padding-left: 0;
    }
   .ft-pub-bottom {
     width: 45%;
     float: right;
     margin-right: 40px;
   }
  }

   @media (min-width: 951px) {
    .free-tote-image {
      width: 33px;
      margin-right: 150px;
    }
    .powr-image-slider {
      display: none;
    }
    .ft-member-favorites {
      display: block !important;
    }
    .free-tote-product-carousel p {
      padding-bottom: 40px;
    }
  }

  @media (min-width: 900px) {
    .free-tote-image {
      width: 33px;
      margin-right: 150px;
    }
  }

  @media (min-width: 797px) {
    .free-tote-image {
      display: block !important;
      width: 33%;
      float: right;
      margin-right: 150px;
    }
    .ft-top-div-words {
      width: 50%;
      padding-top: 50px;
    }
  }

  @media (min-width: 737px) {
    .free-tote-top-div {
      height: 450px;
    }
    .deodorant-thumbnail-mobile {
      display: none;
    }
    .free-tote-image {
      display: block !important;
      width: 52%;
      float: right;
      margin-right: 10px;
      max-width: 450px !important;
    }
    .ft-top-div-words {
      width: 50%;
      padding-top: 50px;
    }
    .ft-signup-btn {
      display: block !important;
      padding: 15px 0px 15px 15px;
      width: 240px;
      background-color: rgb(220, 136, 108);
      color: #fff;
      font-family: 'NBH';
      margin-top: 50px;
    }
    .free-tote-third-div {
      width: 50%;
      float: left;
      height: 500px;
    }
    .free-tote-review-section {
      width: 50%;
      float: right;
    }
    .free-tote-product-carousel {
      clear: both;
      margin-top: 550px;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    .free-tote-second-div {
      top: 55px;
    }
    .free-tote-second-div h3 {
      padding-top: 14px;
    }
  }

  @media (min-width: 525px) {
    .free-tote-publications {
      height: 500px;
    }
  }

  @media (max-width: 400px) {
    .free-tote-review-section h1 {
      font-size: 26px;
    }
    .free-tote-review-section {
      height: 550px;
      width: 100%;
    }
  }

  @media (max-width: 335px) {
    .free-tote-review-section {
      height: 600px;
    }
  }

  @media (max-width: 313px) {
    .free-tote-publications {
       height: 700px;
    }
  }
```

I would like the div .free-tote-second-div to stick to the bottom of the screen when it is scrolled to.

Comment: If you want this div always showing at the bottom of the screen, use `position: fixed;bottom: 0;` if you want this div to scroll in the page and when not visible or when appears stick it to the bottom of the screen, you will need javascript.

Comment: Check up on `position: sticky`

Comment: so ```position:sticky``` only works if you want the div to stick to the top?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to stick the div to the bottom of the page:

`.free-tote-second-div {
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 0px;
}`

Make sure you're modifying line 281 for the mobile view, and line 81 for the desktop view.

Comment: The div in question should be hidden until scrolled to. When it is scrolled to it should remain on the bottom. Is it true this can only be done with javascript?

Comment: I don't think `position: sticky;` will work in your case. I would suggest using a small amount of JavaScript, take a look at https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_navbar_sticky You should be able to achieve what you have described by modyfying the `.sticky` div css and replacing `top:0;` with `bottom:0;`.